# Randomly set background image - Android

Tags: android, random

I have a background set on a login screen, and I want to randomly set the background every time the app is loaded from a pile of images in my drawables folder.  However, my app crashes with every attempt at writing code to do this.

I have my array defined in layout/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="app_name">MyFSU</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

<style name="DefaultButtonText">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#979797</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#f9f9f9</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
</style>

<array name="myImages">
   <item>@drawable/a</item>
   <item>@drawable/b</item>
   <item>@drawable/c</item>
   <item>@drawable/d</item>
   <item>@drawable/e</item>
</array>
```

And then here's my code to actually generate a random image:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

final RelativeLayout background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.back);
Resources res = getResources();
final TypedArray myImages = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.myImages);
final Random random = new Random();

public void backgrounds(View v) {
    int randomInt = random.nextInt(myImages.length());
    int drawableID = myImages.getResourceId(randomInt, -1);
    background.setBackgroundResource(drawableID);
}
```

Logcat is showing a null pointer exception at `<init>`, but I have no clue where that is or how to fix it.  :(

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move

```
final RelativeLayout background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.back);
Resources res = getResources();
final TypedArray myImages = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.myImages);
```

inside `onCreate`, after `setContentView`. setContentView(int), inflate and place the inflated view inside the `Activity` view's hierarchy, allowing you to look for `R.id.back`, in your case, inside it

Comment: Okay, so, this fixed it.  I moved everything relating to the random backgrounds to inside `onCreate(bundle savedInstanceState)`.  That seemed to fix it, and it's pulling random pictures now!  However, every now and then I get a nullpointerexception and a crash, but I think that may be from corrupt resources... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i would make a method that takes a min and max value:

**pseudo code**

```
public static int generateRandomInt(int min,int max)
    {
        return min + (int)(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
    }

public void backgrounds(View v) {
    int randomInt = generateRandomInt(0,myImages.length()-1);
    int drawableID = myImages.getResourceId(randomInt);
    v.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getDrawable(drawableID)); // assuming your array is of resource ids
}
```